# Stylelint: Expected declaration to come before rule - order/order

Tags: sass, stylelint

The code is as follows:

```
    .home-feat2 {
        background-color: stencilColor("color-greyLight");
        img {width: 10rem;}
        margin-bottom: spacing("single");
        @include breakpoint("medium") {
            margin-bottom: 3rem;
        }
    }
```

`Expected declaration to come before rule - order/order` points to the line with `margin-bottom: spacing("single");` however I tried looking up what this error meant but I can't find a lot of descriptive documentation on stylelint. Maybe it's because I just don't understand the terminology, but I'm having trouble finding anything on this subject. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your linters expects you to write **declarations** before **rules**.

In CSS, a *declaration* is the key-value pair of a CSS property and its value, like `margin-bottom: spacing("single")`.
[See a visual representation of a declaration block](http://apps.workflower.fi/vocabs/css/en#declaration-block).

A *rule* is the block defined by one or multiple selectors, containing declarations, like: `img { width: 10rem; }`.
[See a visual representation of a rule set](http://apps.workflower.fi/vocabs/css/en#rule-set).

What it means for you, it means that you should probably write the rule `img {}` after the declarations:

```
    .home-feat2 {
        background-color: stencilColor("color-greyLight");
        margin-bottom: spacing("single");

        @include breakpoint("medium") {
            margin-bottom: 3rem;
        }

        img {width: 10rem;}
    }
```

This specific rule purpose is to allow an *easy to read* code.
When applied, you can see at the first glance that `background-color` and `margin-bottom` are applied to `.home-feat2` and `width` is applied to `img`.

*edit: added some additional informations thanks to jeddy3*

Comment: Good answer. Two additional notes: 1. This is a useful resource for CSS terminology: http://apps.workflower.fi/vocabs/css/en. 2. The linter expects this structure because it makes the code easier to understand, e.g. it's now easier to see that the background color and margin bottom are applied to `.home-feat2`, whereas the width is applied to the `img` element.

Comment: Thanks for the notes, I'll edit the answer to includes your link (great ressource by the way!) and the purpose of the linter rule.